# IF dentro de otro IF

Tags: python

tengo un problema y es que cuando el primer if de edad se cumple el programa corre y anda todo bien. El problema surge cuando el primer if de edad no se cumple pero alguno de los otros si (lo que esta dentro del elif no se ejecuta). Se tiene que usar otro condicional?ㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤㅤ ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................ㅤㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤㅤ ㅤㅤㅤㅤ

```
arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

class Proyecto(tk.Tk):#Contains the methods of the window
    def __init__(self, window) : #initializes the state of an object
        self.wind = window #store the window as a parameter
        self.wind.title('HeartPY')#title of the windows
        self.defaultFont = font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")#Cree el objeto de fuente utilizando el método font.nametofont
        self.defaultFont.configure(family="Bahnschrift SemiLight", size=13) #Utilice el método de configuración en el objeto de fuente
        self.wind.geometry('600x475') #window dimensions
        self.wind.resizable(False, False) #remove the maximize option
        self.windtext = Label(self.wind, text='Calculadora de salud')#title
        self.windtext.pack(ipady= 30)#position
#a container is created
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text ='Ingrese sus datos') #name of the container
        frame.pack(ipady= 20, ipadx = 40, anchor= tk.N) #position of the container
#input age
        self.labeledad = Label(frame, text= 'Edad')#text that appears in front of the input
        self.labeledad.pack(ipady=15, ipadx = 0)#position text
        self.edad = ttk.Combobox(frame, state='readonly') #declare combobox
        self.edad.pack(ipady=0.5, ipadx= 2)#position of the combobox
        self.edad['values'] = ('20 a 29',  '29 a 39', '39 a 49', '+50')#values of the combobox
        self.edad.current(0) #default value
        self.edad.pack(ipady=  0, ipadx= 0) #position input
        self.edad.focus()
#Combobox Gender
        
        self.labelgenero = Label(frame, text = 'Genero')  #text that appears in front of the input
        self.labelgenero.pack(ipady=15, ipadx= 0) #position text
        self.genero = ttk.Combobox(frame, state='readonly') #declare combobox
        self.genero.pack(ipady=0.5, ipadx= 2)#position of the combobox
        self.genero['values'] = ('masculino',  'femenino')#values of the combobox
        self.genero.current(0) #default value
#send data button
        def obtener_info():
                genero = self.genero.get()#save the variables of the gender field
                edad = self.edad.get()#save the variables of the age field
                bpm = int(arduino.readline().decode('utf-8')) #comunication with arduino monitor serial
                NewWind = Toplevel(window) #open a new window
                NewWind.geometry('500x500')#new window dimensions
                NewWind.title('HeartPY')#title new window
                self.wind.withdraw()
                NewWind.update()
                
                def comparacionFem():
                        label_estado = Label(NewWind, text="Su estado de salud es ")
                        label_estado.place(x=100, y=100)
                        if edad == "20 a 29":
                                if bpm >= 78 and bpm <= 94:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es optimo        ")
                                elif bpm < 78 or bpm > 94:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es no optimo")              
                        elif edad == "29 a 39":
                                if bpm >= 80 and bpm <= 96:
                                    label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es optimo        ")
                                elif bpm < 80 and bpm > 96:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es no optimo") 
                        elif edad == "39 a 49":
                                if bpm >= 80 and bpm <= 98:
                                       label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es optimo        ")    
                                elif bpm > 80 and bpm < 98:  
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es no optimo")          
                        if edad == "+50":
                                if bpm >= 84 and bpm <= 102:
                                       label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es optimo        ")
                                elif bpm > 84 and bpm < 102:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es no optimo") 
                                        
                def comparacionMasc():
                        label_estado = Label(NewWind, text="Su estado de salud es")
                        label_estado.place(x=100, y=100)
                        if edad == "20 a 29":
                                if bpm >= 70 and bpm <= 84:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es optimo")
                                elif bpm < 74 or bpm > 84:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es no optimo")  
                                                
                        elif edad == "29 a 39":
                                if bpm >= 74 and bpm <= 84:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es optimo") 
                                elif bpm < 74 and bpm > 84:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es no optimo")    
                        elif edad == "39 a 49":
                                if bpm >= 74 and bpm <= 88:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es optimo")  
                                elif bpm > 74 and bpm < 88:  
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es no optimo")   
                        elif edad == "+50":
                                if bpm >= 76 and bpm <= 88:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es optimo")
                                elif bpm < 76 and bpm > 88:
                                        label_estado.configure(text="Su estado de salud es no optimo")
                                                
                while True:
                        bpm = int(arduino.readline().decode('utf-8')) #comunication with arduino monitor serial
                        Label(NewWind, text=bpm, font="Century_Gothic").place(x=0, y=0) #BPM in tkinter window
                        Label(NewWind, text="Fuente: https://mejorconsalud.as.com/frecuencia-cardiaca-normal-edad-calcularla/").place(x=0, y=475)
                        print(bpm)
                        NewWind.update() #window update
                        if genero == "femenino":
                                comparacionFem()    
                        elif genero == "masculino":
                                comparacionMasc()
                                                                           
        self.boton = Button(frame, text = 'Enviar Datos', command=obtener_info).pack(ipady =0, ipadx= 36, pady=30) #create the button that sends the data
                


if __name__  == '__main__' or 'NewWind':#comprueba si es el archivo main
    window = Tk() 
    aplication = Proyecto(window) 
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tienes que proporcionar un código completo, ejecutable, mínimo. Probé el que publicas (parchando lo que falta) y no muestra errores.

Comment: @CandidMoe Ahi he puesto el codigo completo, cuando se cumple otra condicion de edad (que no sea la primera) no se cambia el texto de los labels

Comment: Te sugiero simplificar el código. Ciertamente no necesitamos un Arduino para probarlo (puedes sustituir las lecturas seriales por asignaciones constantes).

Comment: @CandidMoe Ok, muchas gracias por el consejo. Pero como seria la solucion al problema?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Algunos no queremos instalar arduino y otras cosas para probar un código que no requiere de ello para mostrar el error. Y otros no tienen el tiempo para ponerse a quitar lo no relevante del código. Si querés convencer a más gente de responder tu pregunta, te recomiendo leer lo que te propuse, crear un emcv y ponerlo en lugar de tu código completo o incompleto. Generalmente, no necesitamos conocer el verdadero código.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que he visto el problema:
Para las comparaciones de las bpm, solo en el primer if las evalúas bien, me explico, para el primer ejemplo: Si la edad es de 20 a 29 evalúas si sus bpm están entre 78 y 94, SINO(elif) miras si son menores de 78 **O** mayores de 94.
Para los demás elif miras por ejemplo si la edad es de 29 a 39 y si sus bpm están entre 80 y 96, SINO(elif) miras si sus bpm son menores de 80 **Y** mayores de 96. Por lo que para este caso si las bpm no están entre 80 y 96, si por ejemplo son de 100 bpm nunca se te va a cumplir el elif, ya que 100 es mayor a 96 pero no puede ser menor que 80. La solución a tu problema es programarlo con un ELSE:
**Si las bpm no están entre una determinada venta de valores, estarán en la otra**

Espero haberte ayudado.
Un saludo,